# parsing a file with BufferedReader

Tags: java, string, stream, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I would like to learn more about working/parsing with files and more generally with Strings.

So for that i created a custom .txt file with this input:

```
Function            Time
print()             0:32
find()              0:40
insert()            1:34
```

I want to parse that file and to aggregate how much "functions" have been activated. Also, I want to aggregate the total time that it took for that (i.e., (0.32+0.4+1.34)/0.6 = 2:46 minutes)

For the above data, the output should be:

```
3 functions in total time of 2:46 minutes
```

For the solution, I obviously create `BufferedReader` and parse line by line, but there are lots of spaces, and I am not so great with working with that kind of input. I hope if someone can suggest me the proper way to work with that kind of data.

I will also appreciate any link to exercises of this kind since I am trying to get a job and they ask lots of questions about parsing this kind of data (strings and files).

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Line by line parsing plus splitting the lines by an arbitrary amount of whitespaces would result in a `String[]` per line. Try it, it's not that hard...

Comment: *FYI:* `0:32 + 0:40 + 1:34`, i.e. `32 seconds + 40 seconds + 1 minute 34 seconds` is `2:46`, e.g. `2 minutes 46 seconds `, not the decimal number `3.43`, whatever time that is.

Comment: @Andreas yea thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general terms, you should process the file line by line. For each line, you can use the `split` function to split the line into several parts (from `String` to `String[]`). Notice that the argument of the split function is the character or the regular expression to use to split the original text. For instance, using `str.split("\\s+")` will split the input text treating multiple spaces as a single space. Also, you can use the `trim` function to erase unwanted spaces, end lines, tabs, etc. and then parse the information properly.

Concerning the specifics of parsing time values, Java has several built-in classes and methods to handle local dates, elapsed times, etc. (such as `LocalTime` or `Calendar`). However, in my example, I have built a custom `FuncTime` class to keep things easy.

Here is the code:

```
package fileParser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;


public class FileParser {

    private static class FuncTime {

        private int seconds;
        private int minutes;


        public FuncTime() {
            this.seconds = 0;
            this.minutes = 0;

        }

        public FuncTime(int seconds, int minutes) {
            this.seconds = seconds;
            this.minutes = minutes;
        }

        public void accumulate(FuncTime ft) {
            this.seconds += ft.seconds;
            while (this.seconds >= 60) {
                this.seconds -= 60;
                this.minutes += 1;
            }
            this.minutes += ft.minutes;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.minutes + ":" + this.seconds;
        }
    }


    private static void parseInfo(String fileName) {
        // Create structure to store parsed data
        Map<String, FuncTime> data = new HashMap<>();

        // Parse data from file
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            // Skip header (DATA FILE MUST ALWAYS CONTAIN HEADER)
            String line = reader.readLine();
            // Begin to process from 2nd line
            line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                // Split funcName and time
                String[] lineInfo = line.split("\\s+");
                String funcName = lineInfo[0].trim();
                // Split time in minutes and seconds
                String[] timeInfo = lineInfo[1].split(":");
                int seconds = Integer.valueOf(timeInfo[1].trim());
                int minutes = Integer.valueOf(timeInfo[0].trim());

                // Store the function name and its times
                FuncTime ft = new FuncTime(seconds, minutes);
                data.put(funcName, ft);

                // Read next line
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Print parsed information
        FuncTime totalTime = new FuncTime();
        for (Entry<String, FuncTime> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            String funcName = entry.getKey();
            FuncTime ft = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(funcName + " " + ft);
            totalTime.accumulate(ft);
        }
        // Print total
        System.out.println(data.size() + " functions in total time of " + totalTime);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = args[0];

        parseInfo(fileName);
    }

}
```

You can store the example data you provided in a file named `example.data`:

```
$ more example.data
Function            Time
print()             0:32
find()              0:40
insert()            1:34
```

And run the above code obtaining the following output:

```
insert() 1:34
print() 0:32
find() 0:40
3 functions in total time of 2:46
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
int count = 0;
int totalMinutes = 0;
int totalSeconds = 0;
try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("test.txt"))) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)\\s+(\\d+):(\\d+)");
    for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if (m.matches()) {
            // not used: String function = m.group(1);
            int minutes = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
            int seconds = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
            count++;
            totalMinutes += minutes;
            totalSeconds += seconds;
        }
    }
}
if (count == 0) {
    System.out.println("No functions found");
} else {
    totalMinutes += totalSeconds / 60;
    totalSeconds %= 60;
    System.out.printf("%d functions in total time of %d minutes %d seconds%n",
                      count, totalMinutes, totalSeconds);
}
```

*Output*

```
3 functions in total time of 2 minutes 46 seconds
```